# Reading file line by line with C++ always output 2 lines even if file is different

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream, getline

I need to store each lines of a text document into a vector. However any file text I try, the output is always 2 lines. First one is empty and second one always output: "DONE". I'm on Windows7 X64, using VC++2013.

I have been trying to solve this for many hours. I tried many different approach but the result stay the same. I suspect that "DONE" is the return value from getline() however I don't understand with my code is not working like it should.

```
int main() {

    ifstream hFile("test.txt");

    vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    while (std::getline(hFile, line))
        lines.push_back(line);

    cout << lines[1];

    hFile.close();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It works fine when executing the program from the compilation folder but not in the debug console of VC++...

Comment: I wonder what the contents of `test.txt` are.

Comment: You don't check how many lines you have actually read.

Comment: I tried a file with 3 lines: 123, test and test4 and another file with different content.  I know I should use line.size() to get the size of the vector however I tried 2 different file and lines[0] is always empty and lines[1] always return: "DONE". Nowhere in my file the word "done" is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program looks mostly correct. The only problem is that your code assumes that there are, at least, two lines in your file: if there are few lines, e.g., just one or the files couldn't be opened, the statement

```
cout << lines[1];
```

result in undefined behavior. Did you mean to print each line of the file rather than just the second line?

From the description of the behavior I would suspect that you file either contains the string `DONE` or you are actually executing a different program!

Comment: This line is only for testing purpose. I know I should use line.size() to get the size of the vector however I tried 2 different file and lines[0] is always empty and lines[1] always return: "DONE". Nowhere in my file the word "done" is present.

Comment: @01BTC10: If `2<= lines.size()` and `lines[1]` contains `DONE` after executing the above code I'd bet quite a bit of money on the file actually to contain the string `DONE`! It seems, you are reading a different file than the one you think you are reading. Make sure you are executing the program in the same directory where the file you actually want to read is located. Alternatively, use an absolute path to the file (if you are using Windows, remember that backslashes are escape characters, i.e., you'll need to use `\\` to get one backslash).

Comment: Ok I tested my program by starting it directly from the compilation folder and it is working fine however the problem is always the same from the debug console of VC++. What a waste of time!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, it proves nothing about the count of lines:

```
cout << lines[1];
```

Use `line.size()` to count the read lines. In fact for a file with one line, it's *undefined behavior* to access second item.